# Group on most occuring value of a field in an aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have 2 fields `A` and `B`. The field `A` can take the following values: `[a,b,c,d,e]` and B: `[x,y]`.

I am looking for a single MongoDB aggregation pipeline query that will:

1. Count the number of times each value of `A` appears in my database
2. Display the distribution of the values of `B` for the most occurring value of `A`

**Example:**

Let's say 'c' happens to be the most occurring value of A:

The output would be:

```
{ '_id': { 'A': 'c', 'B': 'x' }, 'count': 43 }
{ '_id': { 'A': 'c', 'B': 'y' }, 'count': 13 }
```

The only way I managed to do that is by hard coding `A:c` into my `"$match"` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can infer the aggregate pipeline from the output. The `_id` field has two keys `A` and `B` which infers that the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** key is made up of the two keys and getting the count is by calling the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator.

**Populate Test Collection**

Suppose we generate a test collection with the following documents

```
db.collection.insert([
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "e", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "a", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "a", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "b", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "x" },
    { "A": "a", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "a", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "b", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "b", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "b", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "b", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "b", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "c", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "e", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "e", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "d", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "d", "B": "y" },
    { "A": "d", "B": "y" }
])
```

Then the following initial pipeline will group the documents on those two keys and gets the count:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "A": "$A", "B": "$B" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "e",
        "B" : "y"
    },
    "count" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "c",
        "B" : "x"
    },
    "count" : 11
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "b",
        "B" : "y"
    },
    "count" : 5
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "b",
        "B" : "x"
    },
    "count" : 1
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "e",
        "B" : "x"
    },
    "count" : 1
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "d",
        "B" : "y"
    },
    "count" : 3
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "a",
        "B" : "y"
    },
    "count" : 2
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "a",
        "B" : "x"
    },
    "count" : 2
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "c",
        "B" : "y"
    },
    "count" : 2
}
```

From observation, document #2 with count 11 has "c" as the most occurring value:

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "A" : "c",
        "B" : "x"
    },
    "count" : 11
}
```

---

Having gotten this far, you can further aggregate to get the key with the most counts. You need another **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline which will group the results from the previous pipeline by the `A` key, create a list with the document details i.e.
the counts and the corresponding `B` value with that count. You also need the count field for each group of `A` values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "A": "$A", "B": "$B" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.A",
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "B": "$_id.B",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" } 
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "e",
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "B" : "y",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "B" : "x",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "count" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "c",
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "B" : "x",
            "count" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "B" : "y",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "count" : 13
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "b",
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "B" : "y",
            "count" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "B" : "x",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "count" : 6
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "d",
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "B" : "y",
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "count" : 3
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "a",
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "B" : "y",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "B" : "x",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "count" : 4
}
```

---

At this stage you just need to sort the documents on the count field and return the top document when the documents are ordered by descending direction:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "A": "$A", "B": "$B" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.A",
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "B": "$_id.B",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

which yields:

```
{
    "_id" : "c",
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "B" : "x",
            "count" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "B" : "y",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "count": 13
}
```

---

Although the output is different from the desired structure, it still sufficiently addresses the questions

**1.** Count the number of times each value of `A` appears in my database -> required pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "A": "$A", "B": "$B" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.A",                
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" }
        }
    }
])
```

**2.** Display the distribution of the values of `B` for the most occurring value of A

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "A": "$A", "B": "$B" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.A",
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "B": "$_id.B",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 }
])
```